# How to append plus and minus to number input and update value

Tags: javascript, html, validation, input, numbers

I am building a form for a travel website and have a section where it says 'add participant'. I have used the number input so when it is set to '1' it adds a group of fields, and repeats until the maximum of 5.

I have now appended a plus and minus button to change the value so the form looks more appealing but although the value is changing, it is not registering to show the hidden fields.

Here is my code for changing the value with the appended buttons:

```
    $(".test-fill").append('<div class="inc button">+</div><div class="dec button">-</div>');

    $(".button").on("click", function() {

    var $button = $(this);
    var oldValue = $button.parent().find(".test").val();

    if ($button.text() == "+") {
      var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
    } else {
   // Don't allow decrementing below zero

        if (oldValue > 0) {
          var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
        } else {
          newVal = 0;
        }
       }

       $button.parent().find(".test").val(newVal);

       });
```

Here is my code for showing the hidden fields depending on the value:

```
    //Hide the field initially
$("#hide1, #hide2").hide();

//Show the text field only when the third option is chosen - this doesn't
$('#awesome').change(function() {
    if ($("#awesome").val() == "1") {
        $("#hide1").slideDown();
        $("#hide2, #hide3, #hide4, #hide5").slideUp();
    }
    else if ($("#awesome").val() == "2") {
        $("#hide2").slideDown();
        $("#hide3, #hide4, #hide5").slideUp();
    }
    else if ($("#awesome").val() == "3") {
        $("#hide3").slideDown();
        $("#hide4, #hide5").slideUp();
    }
    else if ($("#awesome").val() == "4") {
        $("#hide4").slideDown();
        $("#hide5").slideUp();
    }
    else if ($("#awesome").val() == "5") {
        $("#hide5").slideDown();
    }
    else {
        $("#hide1, #hide2, #hide3, #hide4, #hide5").slideUp();
    }
});
```

and here is my HTML:

```
<p>Add participant<br />
<div class="test-fill">
[number number-658 min:0 max:5 id:awesome class:test]
</div>

<div id="hide1">
<h4>Second Participants Information</h4>
<p>Full Name<br />
[text text-995]</p>

<p>Sex<br />
[text text-500]</p>

<p>Age<br />
[text text-379] </p>

<p>Passport Country of Issue<br />
[text text-591] </p>
</div>

<div id="hide2">
<h4>Third Participants Information</h4>
<p>Full Name<br />
[text text-995]</p>

<p>Sex<br />
[text text-500]</p>

<p>Age<br />
[text text-379] </p>

<p>Passport Country of Issue<br />
[text text-591] </p>
</div>

<div id="hide3">
<h4>Fourth Participants Information</h4>
<p>Full Name<br />
[text text-995]</p>

<p>Sex<br />
[text text-500]</p>

<p>Age<br />
[text text-379] </p>

<p>Passport Country of Issue<br />
[text text-591] </p>
</div>

<div id="hide4">
<h4>Fifth Participants Information</h4>
<p>Full Name<br />
[text text-995]</p>

<p>Sex<br />
[text text-500]</p>

<p>Age<br />
[text text-379] </p>

<p>Passport Country of Issue<br />
[text text-591] </p>
</div>

<div id="hide5">
<h4>Sixth Participants Information</h4>
<p>Full Name<br />
[text text-995]</p>

<p>Sex<br />
[text text-500]</p>

<p>Age<br />
[text text-379] </p>

<p>Passport Country of Issue<br />
[text text-591] </p>
</div>
```

(I am using contact form 7 for wordpress)

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, your problem is this: 
The button clicks aren't changing the select field and hence not carrying out your functionality.

The easiest way around this is to place the code inside your change event
*$('#awesome').change(function() {} ...*

inside a function (**changeTheForm()**), then call this just after you've adjusted the select input's value.

```
$button.parent().find("#awesome").val(newVal);
// you want your code to run now..
changeTheForm();
```

You don't need to rely on detecting the select change/ the select input, in fact it would be better just to remove it and rework your script a little, in my opinion.

You'll likely encounter an error with NaN when reading the value of a select field where no options are selected, though. It should be easy for you to find a way around this.

Comment: The button clicks are changing the number in the field, however it isn't registering that it is a value. When I click the spinner buttons that come as default with the number input, that registers it is a value and triggers the function.